# Maptype=toner produces maps in color, not black and white

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap, stamen-maps

I am having trouble producing a black and white stamen map using maptype=toner. Instead the code produces a map that is in color (see below). In addition, I can't figure out how to control the size of city and state names, and also am not sure how to turn certain labels off (for example if I don't want city names to be shown but want state names). Here is my code:

```
mapbox.hud <- c(-74.2, 41, -73.5, 43)
Hudson.River <- get_map(location = mapbox.hud, source = "stamen", maptype = 
"toner", zoom=10,crop=T, force=T)
ggmap(Hudson.River)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `get_stamenmap`:

```
library(ggmap)
mapbox.hud <- c(-74.2, 41, -73.5, 43)
Hudson.River <- get_stamenmap(bbox=mapbox.hud, maptype="toner", zoom=10, crop=T, force=T)
ggmap(Hudson.River)
```

[image]